# Stack Exchange site to ask for resource on translations of book titles

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a site in the SE network where it is on topic to ask the following question?

> I'm looking for the Italian title of some English books. Is there any
>   database, website or service where I can easily find this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for an off-site resource, which is usually prohibited on every SE site.

If you are just asking:

> I'm looking for the Italian title of some English books.

There is currently no site I can imagine that would fit. If it has a specific genre, maybe it could site on the SE site for that genre, like SciFi, Academia, etc. (You should check in the Help that it is allowed to ask such questions on those sites) The general Literature SE site didn't make it through the beta phase.

Comment: Nice, I've found out that the question has already been answered on Academia: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28591/how-to-find-book-titles-in-other-languages

Comment: "I'm looking for the Italian title of some English books." is on-topic for the [current Literature site](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), which is chugging along fine (though we'd prefer one question per book)